# Slow backend after WooCommerce update

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

I have an online store in WordPress that works with WooCommerce. The page has a custom theme that has not been maintained for years, so the errors I find are many.

The problem is that I needed an urgent WooCommerce update and since then the back of my store has been very slow. If I try to access products or orders, I experience loading times of more than 40 seconds. Also if I try to search for an order by its id.

Before, the problems were limited to WooCommerce, but a few days ago we found ourselves experiencing exaggerated waiting times when trying to access the WordPress desktop. Skip the CloudFlare 503 error.

I have contacted the support of my hosting host and we were seeing that it had a function that gave errors hundreds of times during loading:

```
/* Remove action cancel unpaid orders / /*/
add_action(‘init’,’remove_woocommerce_process_registration’);

function remove_woocommerce_process_registration() {

error_log('Eliminamos llamada a wc_cancel_unpaid_orders() - ');

remove_action('woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_orders', 'wc_cancel_unpaid_orders');
}
```

I decided to delete it and then other errors began to appear that did not appear before, especially this:

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: id was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), wp, WP->main, WP->parse_request, do_action_ref_array('parse_request'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, rest_api_loaded, WP_REST_Server->serve_request, WP_REST_Server->dispatch, WP_REST_Server->respond_to_request, WC_REST_CRUD_Controller->get_items, WC_REST_Orders_V2_Controller->prepare_object_for_response, Automattic\\WooCommerce\\Admin\\API\\Orders->get_formatted_item_data, Automattic\\WooCommerce\\Admin\\Overrides\\Order->get_data_without_line_items, WC_Order->get_order_number, apply_filters('woocommerce_order_number'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_Seq_Order_Number_Pro->get_order_number, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.', referer: https://negrillo.es/wp-admin/edit.php?post_status=wc-processing&post_type=shop_order
```

I then proceeded to change the calls to the ids, and then I will receive errors with the database.

Comment: Well basically you have some custom code somewhere calling the id the incorrectly, don't use `$wocoommerce_object->id`, instead use `$woocommerce_object->get_id();`
there are probably alot of  thoose best thing you can do is change the theme altogether